# Automatically join lines by snap

Tags: qgis, line, snapping, vertices, v.clean

After I smoothed a layer of lines I lost the connection with some vertices.

[image]

Is there an automatic way to connect the various lines to avoid doing it manually?

[image]

I think the best thing is to use [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.clean.html) but I am not sure of the right parameters that should be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try ["Snap geometries to layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer) from Processing Toolbox. You can select the same layer as input and reference.

In your case I would try the *"Behavior"* (Move end points only), as well as a suiting *"Tolerance"*.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to enter a tolerance of 0.010000 because I didn't get any results with that in your example

Comment: @ddomizia Don't look at my example in that case. I just quickly drew some lines over the world using degrees. From your screenshot I assume you are using UTM and therefore meters, choose a suiting tolerance for your case. Seeing your scale and assuming you are using a "normal" display, I'd say something between 1m and 10m. But this also depends on your chosen behavior and where the next vertex is. Just play a little with the settings.

Comment: Okay, I have to thank you! After all the right parameters for my layer were "Tolerance: 25,00000000" and "Behavior: Prefer closest points insert extra vertices where required". With your solution my layer keeps all attributes and above all I don't notice any errors in the geometries. The result obtained with the GRASS v.clean tool was unfortunately very bad.